# Asp.Net aspparse circular reference error only on command line build

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, cruisecontrol.net, msbuild-4.0

I have an Asp.Net website project that builds fine locally with VS2010 and from the command line with `msbuild`. The problem is its failing on our build server (CruiseControl.net) with this circular file reference issue

```
  /tms/_master/help.master(1): error ASPPARSE: Circular file references are not allowed. [C:\ccnet\working\master\Tms.Rms.Website\tms.metaproj]
  /tms/_master/reporting-detail.master(2): error ASPPARSE: Circular file references are not allowed. [C:\ccnet\working\master\Tms.Rms.Website\tms.metaproj]
  /tms/_master/mvc.master(1): error ASPPARSE: Circular file references are not allowed. [C:\ccnet\working\master\Tms.Rms.Website\tms.metaproj]
```

I don't see anything obvious about the way pages/folders/or controls are laid out as suggested in other questions related to this error, and I have zero feedback from VS2010 locally as it doesn't have the problem at all. (it builds ok)

Anyone know how I can track this issue down locally, or what may be the cause of different build results between machines?

Local build environment: vs2010, msbuild 4.0, building as myself
Build server environment: msbuild 4.0, building as ccnet service account (no vs2010 installed or available)

I also have the same version of ccnet setup locally with he same configuration building successfully.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that the circular reference errors above seem to occur on "nested" master pages with the MasterPageFile attribute. e.g.

```
<%@ Master MasterPageFile="~/_master/base.master" CodeFile="help.master.cs" Inherits="_master_help" %>
```